# wxWidgets Button with vertically aligned text

Tags: wxwidgets

I am not quite sure if I have just missed something in the manual, but I also played around with wxSmith, and I can't seem to find a way to create a wxButton with vertically aligned text (from top to bottom - instead of the standard left to right). Is there such an option ? Or is there another button like class which makes this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In the manual of wxWidgets appear something like this "By default, i.e. if none of the alignment styles are specified, the label is centered both horizontally and vertically." visit this [link](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_button.html)

test with this **wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL**

Also i found a couple of examples that should be helps to you.[link 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/9UYtstGL6tU) , [link 2](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/195121/wxpython-vertical-aligning-failing) 
It´s been a while of i made some codes with wxPython, is a very simple and the rapid development.